# Equation with cos and product

Tags: trigonometry, products

How is it possible to prove that the multiplication from 0 to n of $$\cos{(x/2^k)}$$ with $x=\pi / 4$ is $$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \times \dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2} \times \dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}}{2} \times  ...$$

I tried recurrence but got stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the formula (valid for $0<x<\pi$)
$$
\cos\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}\Bigr)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}
$$
repeatedly. So, for the first terms,
$$
\cos(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\quad \text{and}\quad 
\cos(\pi/8)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\pi/4)}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}.
$$
Do you recognize the first two factors? Do you see the pattern?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that formula

Comment: @Ghuizing, it stems from the pythagorean theorem (as most of trigonometric formulas), (see for example ["*The Pythagorean Theorem*", by Eli Maor](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9309.html))

Comment: Maybe you have seen the double angle formula $\cos 2u=2\cos^2u-1$? Let $u=x/2$ and rearrange.